# LINKER ERROR LNK1169 & LNK2005

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm learning c++ and trying to practice translation units and other things at once, but I'm getting the errors listed on the title. This program is for learning purposes and I've tried to explain what each header and implementation file is suppose to do.

--------CString.h--------

```
#ifndef CSTRING_H
#define CSTRING_H
#include <iostream> 

namespace w1
{
class CString
{
    public:
        char mystring[];
        CString(char cstylestring[]);
        void display(std::ostream &os);
};

std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream &os, CString &c)
{
    c.display(os);
    return os;
}
}
#endif
```

--------process.h-------- prototype for process function

```
void process(char cstylestring[]);
```

--------CString.cpp-------- 
To receive a C-style string in constructor and truncate it by taking the first three characters and storing it in mystring to be later displayed through the function display()

```
#include <iostream> 
#include "CString.h"
#define NUMBEROFCHARACTERS 3   

using namespace w1; 

w1::CString::CString(char stylestring[]) 
{
if (stylestring[0] == '\0')
{
    mystring[0] = ' ';
}
else
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBEROFCHARACTERS; i++)
    {
        mystring[i] = stylestring[i];
    }
}
//strncpy(mystring, stylestring, NUMBEROFCHARACTERS);
}


void w1::CString::display(std::ostream &os)
{
std::cout << mystring << std::endl;
}
```

--------process.cpp-------- receives a C-style string and creates a CString object and then display the possibly truncated version of the c-style string by operator overloading.

```
#include "process.h"
#include "CString.h"
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std; 

void process(char cstylestring[])
{
w1::CString obj(cstylestring); 
std::cout << obj << std::endl;
}
```

--------main.cpp-------- Testing purposes by sending a C-style string to process function.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include "process.h"

using namespace std; 

int main()
{
char themainstring[] = "hiiiii";
process(themainstring);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: how do you build it?

Comment: um i click the debugger trying to run main.cpp

Comment: What is your link error message?

Comment: error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

Comment: error LNK2005: "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl w1::operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class w1::CString &)" (??6w1@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV12@AAVCString@0@@Z) already defined in CString.obj

Comment: Even if you program would build, it would crash because you don't allocate memory for `mystring`.

Answer (score 0):

The `<<` operator is defined multiple time because you define it in an header file that is include from multiple source files.

Either add `inline` modifier so that only one copy will be kept or move the definition in one source file (and only keep the declaration in the header file).

As I have mentioned in my comment, the program would crash at run time because no memory is allocated for `mystring`. If it should be 4 characters long maximum, then you could simply add 4 inside the square bracket as in:

```
char mystring[4];
```

Otherwise, if you need variable size, then using something like `std::vector` might make sense as you would avoid explicit memory management.

**Update**:

*My original answer was complete but since you don't seem to properly understand it, I have added extra details...*

I am talking of the following definition in `CString.h`:

```
std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream &os, CString &c)
{
    c.display(os);
    return os;
}
```

Both `process.cpp` and `main.cpp` include the file `CString.h` which contains that definition twice (once when compiling each of these 2 files).

Comment: wait so when you mentioned that i defined it multiple times. Are these the two scenarios where i defined it?

Comment: void w1::CString::display(std::ostream &os)
    {
     std::cout << mystring << std::endl;
   }

Comment: std::cout << obj << std::endl;

Comment: By the way, usually, it is trivial to find for most compiler or linker errors from their numbers often with examples... Either in the tool documentation, online help or by using a search engine like `google` or `bing`.

Comment: ahhh! I understand now! thank you so much!